# What is the most efficient way to pass some constant arguments to a function in Julia?

Tags: function, closures, julia

Suppose I have the following function

```
function foo(x::Float64, a::Float64)
    if do_some_intense_stuff(a)
        return bar(x)
    else
        return baz(x)
    end
end
```

Let's assume that at runtime `a` will be a constant. But `x` will not. I have to run `foo()` many times, so I would like it to run as fast as possible, which means running `do_some_intense_stuff` as rarely as possible. Because `a` is a constant, at runtime we know which branch the `if` statement should take.

So ideally, I'd do the following:

```
foowrapper(x) = foo(x,a)
Y = [foowrapper(x) for x in lots_of_x]
```

and it would be a lot faster than

```
Y = [foo(x,a) for x in lots_of_x]
```

But that's not what happens. I don't blame the compiler for not optimizing my code since I didn't explicitly tell it that `foo()` will only ever be called with the constant value of `a`. But is there a good way for me to do that?

Of course, I can always get rid of `foo` and just write that `if` statement in the global scope, but that seems inelegant because the rest of the program does not care about the output of `do_some_intense_stuff()`

Update:

To benchmark the solution suggested below, I implemented the functions as follows. I also modified the declaration of `foo()` to make `a` an integer, for obvious reasons:

```
function bar(x::Float64)
    return 2 * x
    #println("Ran bar for value ",x)
end

function baz(x::Float64)
    return -2 * x
    #println("Ran baz for value ",x)
end

@memoize function do_some_intense_stuff(a::Int64)
 return isprime(a + 32614262352646106013967035018546810367130464316134634614)
end
```

And defined `lots_of_x = 1.0:1.0:1000.0`.

Here is the output of `@benchmark Y = [foo(x,a) for x in lots_of_x ]` with and without memoize:

Without:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  109.50 KiB
  allocs estimate:  5001
  --------------
  minimum time:     6.858 ms (0.00% GC)
  median time:      6.924 ms (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        7.067 ms (0.77% GC)
  maximum time:     78.747 ms (49.00% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          707
  evals/sample:     1
```

With:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  39.19 KiB
  allocs estimate:  2001
  --------------
  minimum time:     97.500 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      98.801 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        108.897 μs (1.37% GC)
  maximum time:     2.099 ms (93.76% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
```

Comment: In general I think what you ask for is not possible, as `do_some_intense_stuff` can have side effects (e.g.  modify some global state), even if `a` is a compile time constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps caching the result of your call to `do_some_intense_stuff(a)` will help, e.g. using [Memoize.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Memoize.jl).

Comment: This is very useful, thanks! To benchmark, I extended the MWE with actual definitions for the functions (see above) and for the `lots_of_x` range.

If I memoize `do_some_intense_stuff`, median run time is 0.098 ms.  If I don't memoize, median run time is 6.924ms.

We'll see how well this works in my actual code, but so far this is very promising. I guess the design lesson here is that, if there's a computationally intensive block that affects the result of `foo()` but does not depend on `x`, it should be in its own separate function `do_intense_stuff()` so that it can be memoized.

Comment: Glad it helps! After the first run of the cached function, every further run should only trigger a dictionary look up, so it should be very fast. Keep in mind that `do_some_intense_stuff` should not have side effects, as they would of course not be triggered by the dictionary lookup.

Comment: Yes, got it. I'm pretty new to Julia and generally new to modifying arguments in place, so I probably err on the side of having too few "side effects" rather than too many. E.g. I'm still learning to appreciate the huge efficiency gains of preallocating array output.